# Using `DataParallel` when network needs a shared (constant) `Tensor`

Tags: gpu, pytorch

I would like to use [`DataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.DataParallel) to distribute my computations across multiple GPUs along the batch dimension. My network requires a `Tensor` (let's call it `A`) internally, which is constant and doens't change through the optimization. It seems that `DataParallel` does not automatically copy this `Tensor` to all the GPUs in question, and the network will thus complain that the chunk of the input data `x` that it sees resides on a different GPU than `A`.

Is there a way `DataParallel` can handle this situation automatically? Alternatively, is there a way to copy a `Tensor` to *all* GPUs? Or should I just keep one `Tensor` for each GPU and manually figure out which copy to use depending on where the chunk seen by `forward` resides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap your tensor in `torch.nn.Parameter` and set `requires_grad=False` during it's creation.

`torch.nn.Parameter` **does not mean the tensor has to be trainable**.

It merely means it is part of the model and should be transferred if needed (e.g. multiple GPU).

If that wasn't the case, there is no way for `torch` to know which tensor inside `__init__` is part of model (you could do some operations on tensors and add to `self` just to get something done).

I don't see a need for another function to do just that, though the name might be confusing a little bit.

Comment: Now that `Parameter` will end up in the model's parameter list though. This seems very messy to me. [This blog post](https://erickguan.me/2019/pytorch-parallel-model) seems to indicate that all *buffers* will be copied. Yet that doesn't seem to happen (if I `register_buffer(A)`).

Comment: If that's a concern (IMO it is parameter anyway), see [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-register-buffer-and-register-parameter-of-nn-module/32723). Discussion follows there about `state_dict`. There might be some problems with `buffer` as indicated [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/using-register-buffer-with-dataparallel-and-cuda/29863) though. Direct assignment will only affect a copy, if it's not your case you should be fine I think though